# R S4 Methods Applied to List of Objects in a Class

Tags: r, class, methods, r-s4

I am a fluent, long-time R user and am starting to familiarize myself with classes and methods.  I am still very new to this and working through concepts.

Specifically today I am trying to apply a method to a list of objects, all of which are in a particular, user-generated class.

Take this example:

```
#define car
setClass("car",
  representation(
    name = "character",
    mpg = "numeric"
  )
)

#create some cars
cars <-    lapply(1:nrow(mtcars), function(x) new("car", name = 
rownames(mtcars)[x], mpg = mtcars$mpg[x]))

##SAMPLE MPG GROWTH METHOD
setGeneric("grow.mpg", function(car) {
  standardGeneric("grow.mpg")
})

setMethod("grow.mpg",
  signature("car"),
  function(car){
    old_mpg <- car@mpg
    car@mpg <- car@mpg * .1 + car@mpg
    message(paste("growing mpg on ", car@name, " from ", old_mpg, " to 
    ", car@mpg, sep = ''))
    return(car)
  })

#APPLY METHOD
cars[[1]] <- grow.mpg(cars[[1]])
growing mpg on Mazda RX4 from 25.41 to 27.951
```

This successfully grows mpg by 10% on `cars[[1]]`:

```
cars[[1]]
An object of class "car"
Slot "name":
[1] "Mazda RX4"

Slot "mpg":
[1] 27.951
```

But applying method `grow.mpg` to all of `cars` throws the following error:

```
cars <- grow.mpg(cars)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘grow.mpg’ for 
  signature ‘"list"’
```

So two questions:

1. Why is this?
2. How do I apply `grow.mpg` to all of `cars`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your `grow.mpg` function for objects of class "car". And `class(cars[[1]])` is a "car" but `class(cars)` is "list".

Just like anything else in R (and not really unique to S4 classes), whenever you want to apply the same function to every element in the list and get a new list, back, you just use `lapply`.

```
cars <- lapply(cars, grow.mpg)
```

Comment: oh how easy it is to overlook the simple things when you're deep into a new concept.  I appreciate the help.